# Why does $\omega$ have the same cardinality as $\Bbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is basically as stated in the title. I'm teaching myself logic, so my understanding is quite basic. Could someone show me a proof that $\omega$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{N}$?
Additionally, if you could help me understand why $\omega$ also has the same cardinality as something like $\omega^\omega$?

Comment: Usually, $\mathbb N=\omega$, so you might want to clarify what your symbols mean. Also,$\omega^\omega$ does not have the same cardinality as $\omega$, assuming you're taking $\omega^\omega$ to be the set of functions $\omega\to\omega$. If you mean ordinal exponentiation, then $\omega^\omega$ is a countable ordinal, but I'll await for clarification.

Comment: Yes, I do mean ordinal exponentiation. Apologies for the confusion, I'm quite new to this and I'm not yet used to the language.

Comment: dear DN15913, in order to answer this question we will need to know how $\omega$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are actually *defined* for you! (indeed, for some the two objects are actually synonymous :) )

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom: After looking back at the definitions, it seemed my confusion has cleared up a bit. Defining $\Bbb{N}$ as the set of natural numbers, and $\omega$ as a limit ordinal, am I right in saying that omega is just a way of ordering the natural numbers, and therefore it can't be bigger than the natural numbers? And for my second question, is it correct to say $\omega$ is the same size as $\omega^\omega$ because, again, both objects represent different ways of ordering the same set?